# Is making this `getIndex` optic possible?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Is it possible to make an optic with the following type:

```
getIndex :: Lens.IndexedGetter i a i
```

I couldn't find an existing one and in unsuccessfully trying to write one I got a feeling that it can't be done, but if that's the case I would like to know the explanation for why that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index is defined arbitrarily by the getter, so there is no universal way to create one.

`IndexedGetter i s i` is isomorphic to `s -> (i, i)`, via the following bijection:

```
ito   :: (s -> (i, a)) -> IndexedGetter i s a
iview :: IndexedGetter i s a -> s -> (i, a)
```

`forall s i. IndexedGetter i s i` (the fully quantified type of `getIndex`) would be isomorphic to `forall s i. s -> (i, i)`, but that's not inhabited (it would imply `() -> (Void, Void)` with `s ~ ()` and `i ~ Void`).